# AES Encryption - Different Encrypted Values by Same Key and IV

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, xamarin.ios

I'm having some trouble understanding what's going on here. I'm new to the world of encryption and attempting to get a username and password encrypted before transmitting it over HTTP (sent in a JSON string), decrypting it on the other end.

I have a class that serves as a simple implementation of AES (with hard-coded key/iv):

```
public class SimpleAES
{
    private byte[] key = { 32, 128, 16, 11, 28, 36, 45, 15, 214, 184, 17, 244, 27, 142, 252, 119, 111, 84, 125, 244, 123, 93, 126, 39, 44, 76, 87, 118, 231, 136, 43, 109 };
    private byte[] vector = { 246, 164, 231, 211, 32, 8, 64, 128, 211, 221, 132, 242, 122, 123, 129, 254 };
    private ICryptoTransform encryptor, decryptor;
    private UTF8Encoding encoder;

    public SimpleAES()
    {
        //return;
        RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();
        encryptor = rm.CreateEncryptor(key, vector);
        decryptor = rm.CreateDecryptor(key, vector);
        encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
    }

    public string Encrypt(string unencrypted)
    {
        //return unencrypted;
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(encoder.GetBytes(unencrypted)));
    }

    public string Decrypt(string encrypted)
    {
        //return encrypted;
        return encoder.GetString(Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted)));
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] buffer)
    {
        return Transform(buffer, encryptor);
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] buffer)
    {
        return Transform(buffer, decryptor);
    }

    protected byte[] Transform(byte[] buffer, ICryptoTransform transform)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using( CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write) )
        {
            cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

In my ASP.NET Core Web API (targeting Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.1.0), I have a class library (targeting .NET Standard 2.0) that contains my SimpleAES class. This class also exists in a class library that drives my Xamarin.iOS application, which is built with the latest stable version of Xamarin.iOS, targeting iOS 11.

In the ASP.NET Core Web API, this is what the following statements produce (bs is a SimpleAES object):

`bs.Encrypt("testuser") -->     dgIoOZ5UKsI2isPIbqXFNA==`

`bs.Encrypt("testpass") -->     MZI72tKGu9VPIhF6vXoN4A==`

`bs.Encrypt("testuser72") -->   gpzPtU6pTc6vuvpIaiwb1w==`

`bs.Encrypt("testpass1946") --> E3hamfb+u3AQ1Ip6KhC1gg==`

In the Xamarin.iOS application, this is what the very same statements produce:

`bs.Encrypt("testuser") -->     dgIoOZ5UKsI2isPIbqXFNA==`

`bs.Encrypt("testpass") -->     RCXKi1sGI1N/uiSNBI1JLA==`

`bs.Encrypt("testuser72") -->   7JVjuO3JNtKffSJCQ/Vndg==`

`bs.Encrypt("testpass1946") --> BROGP9AUByLcYFVtXS9FMg==`

Why are these values different? My understanding is that with the same key, IV, mode, and other settings properties, the AES encryption output would be the same across any implementation for any given string.

Furthermore, if I change my statements in the iOS application to create a new SimpleAES object each time, the encryption output is then, correctly, *the same* as my ASP.NET Core Web API encryption output.

The solution (not a good one, and not one that I want) for me is to do this:

`bs.Encrypt("testuser") -->     dgIoOZ5UKsI2isPIbqXFNA==`

`bs = new SimpleAES();`

`bs.Encrypt("testpass") -->     MZI72tKGu9VPIhF6vXoN4A==`

`bs = new SimpleAES();`

`bs.Encrypt("testuser72") -->   gpzPtU6pTc6vuvpIaiwb1w==`

`bs = new SimpleAES();`

`bs.Encrypt("testpass1946") --> E3hamfb+u3AQ1Ip6KhC1gg==`

This produces the correct encryption. Creating a new `SimpleAES` object between each encryption, on the ASP.NET Core Web API, does nothing, and the values stay the exact same.

Does anyone know why this would be behaving in such a way on Xamarin.iOS? Perhaps a garbage collection issue? Is there a problem in the code that could be specific to Xamarin.iOS? I'm just at a loss and do not want to use this solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Side note: Any reason you don't just use a ssl certificate to manage the end-to-end encryption between client/server (so send it over httpS)?

Comment: @Igor -- We are planning on doing this. I already have the Web API running on a development SSL certificate. It was requested of me to *still* encrypt the username and password before passing it to and from the server. I was of the mind that we didn't need to; however, orders are orders!

Comment: You are right, if you are using SSL then you do not need to. Add an SSL and tell them it's done as it fully encrypted. The SSL certificate is better than anything you will build (that is no offence to your coding its just that this has been thought out, designed by, and evolved, by a team with the sole purpose of creating a secure means of data transfer.)

Comment: Try encrypting a few byte arrays.  The string stuff certainly introduces potential variables, such as system specific encoding, line feeds, etc.  I doubt that's the issue, but it's easy to eliminate.

Comment: @zzxyz I think that's a good idea, but I also think that my odd workaround would prove that it's not system specific encoding, but that it's something within either the `RijndaelManaged` implementation or with the implementation of `CryptoStream` or the `ICryptoTransform` interface. Just my thought, though. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @TrevorYokum - Agree, I suspect it will be a dead-end.  Worth making sure, though.

Comment: Have you taken note of [this bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/13a98b89-5f61-48f4-be56-b1dbd5bf8f2f/reuse-icryptotransform-objects-bug-net-462?forum=csharpgeneral)?

Comment: @JohnWu Thanks for the link...it's the little things! This is the answer though, I'll simply have to recreate the `ICryptoTransform` each time.

Comment: It is your job to alert your superiors that they are wasting your time and company time by having you implement this.  SSL/TLS is far more secure and efficient than any system you and your team will come up with.  If a developer on my team chose to do this anyway even though TLS was enabled, I would look upon them with much disfavour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementations of `ICryptoTransform` are not necessarily reusable after you've called `TransformFinalBlock` (which happens automatically when the `CryptoStream` gets closed).  You should be checking the `CanReuseTransform` property before creating another `CryptoStream` with the same transform.

*Except*, as another comment has just mentioned, there's a bug in some versions of the framework where some implementions don't return the correct value for `CanReuseTransform`.  To be on the safe side, you might want to recreate the object every time.

Comment: Yeah, this is the correct answer, unfortunately. I moved the `RijndaelManaged` object to a global declaration and now, whenever `Transform()` is called, the `ICryptoTransform` object is created inside of the parameters.